# How to deploy two grails app to cloudfoundry in separate databases

Tags: mysql, grails, cloud-foundry

Deploying a grails app to cloudfoundry was quite easy.  Now I would like to push another app to cloudfoundry.  However, the 2nd app create tables in the exact same database as my first app.  I understand it will run side by side, however, I do want to treat them as separate entity and would like to run the two apps in two database.  Please tell me how it can be done so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what method/plugin/CLI tools you are using for deployment to Cloud Foundry, but if you're using the [Cloud Foundry Integration](http://grails.org/plugin/cloud-foundry) plugin, this may help.

I was able to deploy 2 separate apps bound to 2 different instances of MySQL services. The key info here is the "binding" of the services to your deployed app. It's possible that you've bound both your apps to one service. If you're using the CFI plugin, issue a `cf-apps` and it will list your apps and what services they are bound to

```
+-------------+----+---------+--------------------------+--------------------+
| Application | #  | Health  | URLs                     | Services           |
+-------------+----+---------+--------------------------+--------------------+
| app1        | 1  | RUNNING | app1.cloudfoundry.com    | mysql-3xxxxxx      |
+-------------+----+---------+--------------------------+--------------------+
| app2        | 1  | RUNNING | app2.cloudfoundry.com    | mysql-exxxxxx      |
+-------------+----+---------+--------------------------+--------------------+
```

If your apps are indeed bound to the same service, just do the following with the CFI plugin

- remove the incorrectly bound app
- issue a cf-create-service service-you-want
- take note of the service name of the newly created app
- re-deploy your second app and bind to the new service you just created

  `grails prod cf-push --services=your-new-service-name-xxxx`

  NOTE: when you deploy, the CLI tool may ask you to optionally bind to the other service (the first app's service), which you don't want, so you'll need to answer appropriately. I'm not sure why it does that even when you've explicitly passed in the `--services` argument with the service you want.

Anyway, it's all in the docs and if you're not using the CFI plugin - IMHO you should - it's pretty awesome plugin.

Comment: I am using grails cloud-foundry plugin, and I never thought I can create more than one dababase services.  Thanks, now I get it, all I need is create another mysql services and have my 2nd app bind to it.  Thanks